# How to force calling of QWidget::paintEvent() when its hovered by other window?

Tags: qt, qt4, widget, paintevent

I have a problem:
I'm creating a widget which displays current date's day number. It's like a button, but it's not derived from `QPushButton` class. Just from `QWidget`. So I've reimplemented `enterEvent()`, `leaveEvent()`, `mousePressEvent()`, `mouseReleaseEvent()`. I do call `update()` inside these methods and widget has realistic button behavior (`paintEvent()` is reimplemented also).
But when I change system date and hover that widget with other window,  my widget doesn't get `paintEvent()` and the old date is displayed. Only when I place mouse over it, widget repaints it's contents.
I guess there is a feature (like buffering) which paints old contents on hovering with other window to avoid unnecessary recalculations. But I need to disable it. Tried to set many attributes (the `Qt::WidgetAttribute` enum). But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should find a way to detect that the system time has changed and call `update()` when that happens. Any other method (like detecting the "hovering" of a window or waiting for a mouse event) will cause the update to occur too late.

Comment: Possible it would be even better. But have no idea how to make it